# Configure sbt to use local maven repo

Tags: scala, sbt

sbt and maven both use the same repo structure.

How to tell to sbt to use the local jars already downloaded by maven to my system in path

file:///home/maven/repo

This setting i want to be applicable to all sbt projects in my system and not for any particular projects

I read we can use something like

resolvers += "Maven local" at "file:///home/maven/repo"

But where to keep this setting to be globally applicable

I want this repo setting to be merged with project specific settings and used.

Sbt 0.13.1
Scala 2.10.4

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It says

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Global-Settings

Settings that should be applied to all projects can go in ~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt (or any file in ~/.sbt/0.13/ with a .sbt extension).

Comment: I want this repo setting to be merged with project specific settings and used.

Comment: I'm around this topic and `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true` is something that is what could help.